# Find specific HttpGet Action in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Consider the following situation. In my controller I have:

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
  ...
}
```

Also I have an `ActionFilterAttribute`, which applies to some other actions of the same controller. In the `OnActionExecuting` method I need to get the `ActionDescriptor` of the `HttpGet` `Edit` action:

```cs
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // as this is called from the same controller, I use
    ActionDescriptor action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor
             .FindAction(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, "Edit");
    ...
}
```

The problem is, that the `FindAction` method returns "reference" to the `HttpPost` `Edit` action in case of `POST` requests. How do I make it to look only for `HttpGet` actions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use maybe attribute ?

```
public class FooAttribute
    {


    }

[FooAttribute]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  ...
}
```

you can check OnActionExecution;
example;

```
var isHasAttribute= filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(FooAttribute), true);
```

Comment: I don't like the idea to add one more attribute to every GET action on my controller.